# How to reload the shortcode content when the database is changing

Tags: shortcode, database, content

I use Wordpress plugin: [**snippets**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) to show some data in database. Everything is OK, however, when I change the content in the database. After that I refresh many time in the page. And the content is not change. I close the web page, and wait for 5 minutes. Reopen the page again, the content is updated.
What happens in my situation? Please give me some suggestion!

In Snippets:

```php
public function some_function() {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_var( 
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT count(ID) as total FROM {$wpdb->prefix}sample_table") 
        );
    return $results;
}
add_shortcode('sample_shortcode', 'some_function');
```

In the Page - I add the shortcode

```
[sample_shortcode]
```

Comment: This is probably caching then, either in the code snippet plugin (if it does that) or on your web server or on your CDN if you have one or on your browser (because of server caching configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Shortcodes don't need to be refreshed, they aren't cached.

Instead it sounds like you have either CDN, page, browser, or database caching. Check for caching plugins that need clearing, and flush any CDN caches you might have.